# Where to find Footer links in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, frontend

Just wanna ask where can I find this it. I thought it was a footer at first but was wrong!

I'm talking about the links in the `white background!`
[image]

Comment: Privacy and Cookie Policy ?

Comment: All in the white background!

Comment: Wait I can't still try what you said because my host server is down!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps to find footer links.

**Step 1: Contact us**

You just need to go to `Stores→ Configuration→ General tab→ Contact Link`
After that, select Enable Contact Us Link to NO

**Step 2: Remove footer links**

For Privacy and Cookie Policy

Go to

> /vendor/magento/module-cms/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

Comment block

```
<referenceBlock name=”footer_links”>
<block class=”Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current” name=”privacy-policy-link”>
<arguments>
<argument name=”label” xsi:type=”string”>Privacy and Cookie Policy</argument>
<argument name=”path” xsi:type=”string”>privacy-policy-cookie-restriction-mode</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

**For Search Terms**

Go to

> vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name=”footer_links”>
<block class=”Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current” ifconfig=”catalog/seo/search_terms” name=”search-term-popular-link”><arguments>
<argument name=”label” xsi:type=”string” translate=”true”>Search Terms</argument>
<argument name=”path” xsi:type=”string”>search/term/popular</argument></arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

**For Orders and Returns**

Go to

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/default.xml
>
> Orders and
>   Returns sales/guest/form

**For Advanced Search**

Go to

> vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name=”footer_links”>
<block class=”Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current” name=”catalog-search-advanced-link”>
<arguments>
<argument name=”label” xsi:type=”string” translate=”true”>Advanced Search</argument>
<argument name=”path” xsi:type=”string”>catalogsearch/advanced</argument><argument name=”attributes” xsi:type=”array”>
<item name=”data-action” xsi:type=”string”>advanced-search</item></argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

**For newsletter**

> /vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="footer">
            <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="form.subscribe" as="subscribe" before="-" template="subscribe.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Hope that our guide will help save your time.